# Что такое падежная рамка?

Tags: лексика

Скажите, пожалуйста, что такое падежная рамка?

Comment: Странно, что кто-то заминусовал вопрос. Мне интересно было разобраться (не был ранее знаком с этим понятием). Поддерживаю вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**«Падежными рамками», или фреймами,** называются допустимые сочетания глагола с существительными определённых падежей. Каждому глаголу соответствует определенный набор падежей (падежная рамка), каждому из падежей соответствует определенный участник ситуации, или *партиципант.*

Например, ситуация, соответствующая глаголу **стоять**, предполагает лишь одного партиципанта, который выражается существительным в именительном падеже <КТО стоит>.

Рамка глагола  **резать** – два существительных в именительном и винительном падежах **<КТО режет ЧТО>**; у глагола **давать** – рамка из трех существительных:  в именительном, дательном и винительном падежах **<КТО дает КОМУ ЧТО>.**

Некоторые **природные процессы и явления** вообще не имеют партиципантов (участников), поэтому у обозначающих эти явления русских глаголов **«пустая» падежная рамка: с существительными они вообще не сочетаются: <светает>, <холодает>.**